# Optimum number of threads for a highly parallelizable problem

Tags: parallel-processing, cluster-computing

I parallelized a simulation engine in 12 threads to run it on a cluster of 12 nodes(each node running one thread). Since chances of availability of 12 systems is generally less, I also tweaked it for 6 threads(to run on 6 nodes), 4 threads(to run on 4 nodes), 3 threads(to run on 3 nodes), and 2 threads(to run on 2 nodes). I have noticed that more the number of nodes/threads, more is the speedup. But obviously, the more nodes I use, the more expensive(in terms of cost and power) the execution becomes.

I want to publish these results in a journal so I want to know if there are any laws/theorems which will help me to decide the optimum number of nodes on which I should run this program?

Thanks,
Akshey

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How have you parallelised your program and what is inside each of your nodes ?

For instance, on one of my clusters I have several hundred nodes each containing 4 dual-core Xeons.  If I were to run an OpenMP program on this cluster I would place a single execution on one node and start up no more than 8 threads, one for each processor core.  My clusters are managed by Grid Engine and used for batch jobs, so there is no contention while a job is running.  In general there is no point in asking for more than one node on which to run an OpenMP job since the shared-memory approach doesn't work on distributed-memory hardware.  And there's not much to be gained by asking for fewer than 8 threads on an 8-core node, I have enough hardware available not to have to share it.

If you have used a distributed-memory programming approach, such as MPI, then you are probably working with a number of processes (rather than threads) and may well be executing these processes on cores on different nodes, and be paying the costs in terms of communications traffic.

As @Blank has already pointed out the most efficient way to run a program, if by efficiency one means 'minimising total cpu-hours', is to run the program on 1 core.  Only.  However, for jobs of mine which can take, say, a week on 256 cores, waiting 128 weeks for one core to finish its work is not appealing.

If you are not already familiar with the following terms, Google around for them or head for Wikipedia:

- Amdahl's Law
- Gustafson's Law
- weak scaling
- strong scaling
- parallel speedup
- parallel efficiency
- scalability.

Comment: +1; once you understand all the terms on Mark's list, you'll be much better situated to answer your own question and write up the "performance" part of your paper.

Answer (score 2):

"if there are any laws/theorems which will help me to decide the optimum number of nodes on which I should run this program?"

There's no such general laws, because every problem has slightly different characteristics.

You can make a mathematical model of the performance of your problem on different number of nodes, knowing how much computational work has to be done, and how much communications has to be done, and how long each takes.   (The communications times can be estimated by the amount of commuincations, and typical latency/bandwidth numbers for your nodes' type of interconnect).    This can guide you as to good choices.

These models can be valuable for understanding what is going on, but to actually determine the right number of nodes to run on for your code for some given problem size, there's really no substitute for running a scaling test - running the problem on various numbers of nodes and actually seeing how it performs.   The numbers you want to see are:

- Time to completion as a function of number of processors: T(P)
- Speedup as a function of number of processors: S(P) = T(1)/T(P)
- Parallel efficiency: E(P) = S(P)/P

How do you choose the "right" number of nodes?  It depends on how many jobs you have to run, and what's an acceptable use of computational resources.

So for instance, in plotting your timing results you might find that you have a minimum time to completion T(P) at some number of processors -- say, 32.  So that might seem like the "best" choice.   But when you look at the efficiency numbers, it might become clear that the efficiency started dropping precipitously long before that; and you only got (say) a 20% decrease in run time over running at 16 processors - that is, for 2x the amount of computational resources, you only got a 1.25x increase in speed.  That's usually going to be a bad trade, and you'd prefer to run at fewer processors - particularly if you have a lot of these simulations to run.  (If you have 2 simulations to run, for instance, in this case you could get them done in 1.25 time units insetad of 2 time units by running the two simulations each on 16 processors simultaneously rather than running them one at a time on 32 processors).

On the other hand, sometimes you only have a couple runs to do and time really is of the essence, even if you're using resources somewhat inefficiently.  Financial modelling can be like this -- they need the predictions for tomorrow's markets *now*, and they have the money to throw at computational resources even if they're not used 100% efficiently.

Some of these concepts are discussed in the "Introduction to Parallel Performance" section of any parallel programming tutorials; here's our example, https://support.scinet.utoronto.ca/wiki/index.php/Introduction_To_Performance

Answer (score 0):

Increasing the number of nodes leads to diminishing returns.  Two nodes is not twice as fast as one node; four nodes even less so than two.  As such, the optimal number of nodes is always one; it is with a single node that you get most work done per node.